# How to parse geojson files with python?

Tags: python, dictionary, geopandas

I added .geojson files that I try to parse, but when I run the code it gives an error like;
KeyError: 'area', I know its means but my question is how can I achieve the keys inside raw_airport.loc

[https://dosya.co/93s8tuqpr86m/gates-and-ramps.geojson.html](https://dosya.co/93s8tuqpr86m/gates-and-ramps.geojson.html%20https://dosya.co/5to7l7ngutew/taxiways-and-runways.geojson.html)
https://dosya.co/5to7l7ngutew/taxiways-and-runways.geojson.html

```
import geopandas as gpd
raw_airport = gpd.read_file('./taxiways-and-runways.geojson')

runway_paths = (
    raw_airport.loc[lambda x: x['area'] != 'yes']
               .loc[lambda x: x['aeroway'] == 'runway']
)

taxiway_paths = (
    raw_airport.loc[lambda x: x['area'] != 'yes']
               .loc[lambda x: x['aeroway'] == 'taxiway']
               .loc[:, ['geometry']]
)

raw_stands = gpd.read_file('./gates-and-ramps.geojson')

stands = raw_stands.dropna(subset=['ref'])
```

Comment: the URLs to the geojson files in question don't work.  Can you fix

Answer (score 0):

After running, at the right side you will see the "Variable Explorer" you can see the details on there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Yor problem is probably that keys are sometimes missing, causing expressions like `x['area']` to throw a `KeyError`. If you use the [`.get` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) (i.e, `x.get('area')` instead, you get `None` (or a default value of your choice) when the key is missing.